# case when vs sql joins vs native merge vs formats

Tags: sql, sas

I have to deal with a lot of code that I feel should run much faster, and I suspect that some of the issue is related to over use of `case when` in `PROC SQL`.

An example of code taken from a PROC SQL query would be:

```
 (case 
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL in ('F2F' 'F2' 'ME' 'VI' 'AP') then 'F2F'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL in ('T' 'CB' 'CE' 'VOICE') then 'TEL'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL='' and AFFC_BRANCH in ('CC_FR' 'CC_GENT' 'CC_LIEGE' 'CC_NL') then 'TEL'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL in ('DM_EMAIL' 'EMAIL' 'EMAIL_PS' 'OE' 'EMA' 'DM_' 'CI' 'LI' 'MP') then 'EMAIL'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL in ('DM_LETTER' 'MA') then 'MAIL'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL in ('EMAIL_OLB' 'OB') then 'IM'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL in ('' 'OT' 'SM' 'EMESSAGE' 'OC') and DWH_CTI_CONTACT.CTIC_CHANNEL='' then 'OTHER'
when t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID=. and DWH_CTI_CONTACT.CTIC_CONTACT_ID^=. and t3.AFFC_CHANNEL ='' and DWH_CTI_CONTACT.CTIC_CHANNEL^='' then DWH_CTI_CONTACT.CTIC_CHANNEL
  end) AS Channel
```

This type of instance could be recoded in various ways, using lookup tables used with SQL joins or merging with SAS, or probably using formats (that I haven't looked into much). Maybe there are yet other ways that I don't know about.

Before I start modifying all this code (there's a lot of it...), I would like to know what is the best practice, given that my main concern is speed.

Comment: I love the usage of `t3.AFFC_AFF_CONTACT_ID^=.` :)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that such basic `case when` statements would be the cause of performance issues.  Much more likely is what is happening in the `from` clause.

Comment: Proc SQL can be convenient; sometimes you just need the syntax. For non-trivial operations (joins, anti-joins,...) it is barely usable IMHO.

Comment: @lad2025 you mean in contrast to `is not MISSING` ? It's not my code but it's more compact, and more readable to me, is that bad practice ? Would it impact performance ?

Comment: Be studious before changing working code for optimization purposes. Don't rely on suspicions. Run traces to find bottlenecks and benchmark performance changes observed in test queries that reduce the functional work expected in the select. I agree with @Gordon performance more likely impacted by from clauses, as well as grouping and possibly remote libraries

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I meant compact syntax

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper . . . Yes, it is bad practice.  At least in my opinion, even `proc sql` code should balance more toward the SQL syntax than the SAS syntax.  After all, you might want to make the query a pass-through query one day.  Or, someone more familiar with SQL might be reading the code.

Comment: You do not have an ELSE clause and it is not at all obvious that your WHEN clauses cover every possible combination of the four variables you are testing.

Comment: Many good points thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is difficult to advise on performance issues without taking a high-level view of the whole program. That said, I don't think the choice of logic for this sort of lookup is likely to make much of a difference to overall performance - in SAS, any option that minimises disk I/O is usually close to optimal.

All other things being equal, my suggestion would be to look for an option that strikes a balance between ease of maintenance and avoiding repetitive code. To that end, I'd probably go with lookup tables, as they're easy for other people to pick up (especially for those new to SAS) and you can append rows as needed without changing your code if new categories arise.

If you want to avoid incurring lots of extra disk I/O from using lookup tables in SQL joins, consider creating appropriate indexes on them, and using `sasfile` statements to buffer the smaller ones in memory before using them.